# Proposition 3.1 of Hörmander's paper on Hypoelliptic Second PDE

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

I am struggling a little in the proof of Proposition 3.1 of Hörmander's  "Hypoelliptic second order differential equations". In particular, the following does not sound true to me.

[image]

The function $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto(1+|\xi|^2)^{-1}\in \mathbb{L}_{loc}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $p\geq 1$ and decay at infinity. Ok, but then? Maybe I am misunderstanding the statement or missing something. May someone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The statement is about the *inverse Fourier transform* of $(1+\lvert\xi\rvert^2)^{-1}$, which is (possibly up to a constant) given by the [Bessel potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_potential)
$$ G_2(x) = \frac1{4\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{\pi \lvert x\rvert^2}{y} - \frac{y}{4\pi}\right)\, y^{-\frac{d}2}\,\mathrm{d}y.$$
This can be verified to decrease exponentially in $x$; note that this also follows from general properties of Fourier transforms, as the kernel $\hat K = (1+\lvert\xi\rvert^2)^{-1}$ is smooth.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did not know about Bessel potential. About your last statement, I do not think smoothness is enough. In this case, I think you can prove the exponential decays, but you need that after a certain order, the kernel's derivatives are uniformly bounded in $\mathbb{L}^1$. The proof I have in mind is actually the same as Lebesgue-Riemann's Lemma. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: You're right, you do need a bit more for exponential decay. Your approach sounds plausible, and there is also a more general principle which is quoted in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133632/fourier-from-analyticity-to-exponential-decay-what-prevents-optimal-decay) from Reed & Simon.

Comment: Amazing. In Reed and Simon, this result is not proven but given as a guided exercise. I wrote a complete proof of it that unfortunately, I can't upload here; at any rate, it was very instructive. It is worth observing that  $\hat{K}$, in general, is not in $\mathbb{L}^1$, so you must take some derivatives of it: you apply that result and find an exponential decay at infinity. Moreover, you find a possible blowup at the origin (which is the case since we are talking about the fundamental solution of a hypoelliptic operator).